# How to send Shipping Cost to paypal from cart

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, paypal, e-commerce

I'm trying to send the Shipping amount of the cart to paypal. Paypal is not receiving the amount of  an entire cart, but it will work if I do the shipping on each item in the cart. Has anyone successfully sent the shipping amount of an entire cart to paypal and not foreach line item?

Here is what I've tried:

```
    @Html.Hidden("cmd", "_cart")
    @Html.Hidden("upload", "1")
    @Html.Hidden("business", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BusinessAccountKey"])

    @Html.Hidden("first_name", Model.UserShippingInfo.FirstName)
    @Html.Hidden("last_name", Model.UserShippingInfo.LastName)
    @Html.Hidden("address1", Model.UserShippingInfo.Address)
    @Html.Hidden("city", Model.UserShippingInfo.City)
    @Html.Hidden("state", Model.UserShippingInfo.State)
    @Html.Hidden("zip", Model.UserShippingInfo.Zip)
    @Html.Hidden("shipping", @shippingCost.ToString("N2"))
    @Html.Hidden("amount", @totalCost.ToString("N2"))

    @foreach (CartLine item in Model.Cart.Lines)
    {

        @Html.Hidden("item_name_" + itemCount, item.Product.Name)
        @Html.Hidden("item_number_" + itemCount, item.Product.ProductID)
        @Html.Hidden("amount_" + itemCount, item.Product.Price.ToString("N2"))
        @Html.Hidden("quantity_" + itemCount, item.Quantity)
@*      @Html.Hidden("shipping_" + count, item.Product.Price.ToString())
        @Html.Hidden("handling_" + count, 0)*@

        itemCount++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. If I use the 'handling_cart' variable it works.

```
@Html.Hidden("handling_cart", @shippingCost.ToString("N2"))
```

is this the correct way to approach it for a cart?